# Problemas con array desde un while

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

tengo dos tablas relacionadas **"Amigos"** y **"Mensajes"** hago una consulta que me arroja todos los ids de mis amigos para luego mandar ese resultado via ajax y hacer una evaluacion con ese resultado con un "if", de hecho no tengo ningun problema, me arroja el resultado esperado, el problema es que no se como hacceder a ese resultado. me explico con coigo para mejor entendimiento

```
session_start();
include="conexion.php";

//esta es la consulta y el resultado es exitoso
 $query=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM
   amigos RIGHT JOIN
   mensajes ON amigos.para = mensajes.id_user ");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 

      echo json_encode(array("usuarios"=>$row["id_user"]));

 }
  //este es el resultado de mi consulta me esta arrojando justamente los ids que esperaba
    {"usuarios":26}, {"usuarios":6}, {"usuarios":8}, {"usuarios":19}
```

Bueno me explico, ese resultado lo mando con el json_encode para atras y en el archivo **js**  cuando recivo esa data lo que me gustaria hacer lo siguiente:

```
//ejemplo en el success
success:function(data){
 console.log(data)//por la consola puedo ver el resultado
  //un ejemplo muy simple para que se pueda entender 
     if (data["usuarios"]==26 || data["usuarios"]==13){

       alert("numero de usuario no autoridado");
  }
}
```

Como ven el codigo es muy simple y entendible creo, ahora no me hace nada con ese codigo ni me muestra un error o algo , es obio que algo anda mal o no estoy haciendo algo correcto agradeceria cualquier ayuda gracias

Comment: Estas usando `json_encode` con cada iteración cuando lo que deberias hacer es  almacenar toda la información en un array y luego usar la funcion `json_encode` . Probablemente por ahi iran tus problemas. Aparte es bastante ineficiente hacer un `SELECT *` cuando solo necesitas un campo

Comment: entiendo muchas gracias por responder, como lo arias en tu caso para obtener lo que quiero excusame soy novato

Comment: Yo crearia un array `$retorno = array();` y luego en cada iteración haría `$retorno [] = array("usuarios"=>$row["id_user"])` y despues del while `echo json_encode($retorno)` Eso si, en javascript tendras que tratarlo como un array de arrays.

Comment: podrias armar un ejemplo con codigo de verdad estoy poco confundido por que la verdad que nececito esa consulta con esos ids para lograr lo que quiero si no es mucha molestia porfis